# After Create redirect to other controller Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes

When a User create a new account on my app, I want to redirect him to another controller, lets say, a preferences controller.

But I don't know how to do it, the user is created, but it is not been redirect to the new page

Here is the create from user

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if params[:user][:newMusician]
    @user.preference = Preference.new
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome"
      redirect_to "/preference/edit/"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :preferences
```

Just to add, if the relation is has_one, should I still pluralize ? Because each user have just one preference

Another doubt, I just need the edit action in my preferences right ?

Thanks! (Rails 4 Ruby 2)

Comment: Where is `@usuario` defined? Try changing your redirect to `redirect_to @user.preference`

Comment: @kobaltz what do you mean with "defined"? If I redirect_to user.preference which action it will use ? Index I believe right ?

Comment: You can try `edit_users_preference_path(@user)`

Comment: In your create action, I do not see where `@usuario` is being defined.

Comment: Just a typo when translating to post the question here on StackOverflow, read user instead of usuario

Comment: Btw, got an undefined method on your sugestion

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run `rake routes`. You should get a route like:

Path (Helper) | Method | URL | Controller#action

```
edit_user_preference | GET | users/:user_id/preferences/:id/edit | preferences#edit
```

Prepend the word path and pass the variables `user_id` and `id` to the helper method instead of `"/preference/edit/"`:

`edit_user_preference_path(@user.id, @preference.id)`

You'll also need an update action to update the record.

Comment: Thanks Cortex, the page is redirecting now, but I'm receiving an uninitialized constant PreferencesController

Comment: On a URL like : localhost/user/14/preference/14

Comment: Sure, here is the repo https://github.com/Revokee/NewMusicJungle, but the models are on portuguese... And consider Preference = Musician (Musico, on portuguese). Edit: Here is my Facebook, I don't want to post my email here, but you can chat with me on https://www.facebook.com/eduardo.almeida.754918